# Using JSON Instead of MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, database, web-applications

I have an application that create child-applications automatically for users, I'm storing child-apps PHP files on sub directories, but I'm confused where to store the child application DATA, for example :

- I'm storing on Master Application MySQL DB : Details about applications created, and owners, and I'll need to store for child applications some details about it's users, and some images uploaded paths by them, Is it good to store theses data on JSON files ( User_ID.JSON ) ?

For JSON solution :
I already created the User PHP OOP Class, and on page load, I'll get all infos about User in the Object.

Please i need advices.

Thanks in Advance.
and Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eh, JSON is more for data transit/interchange between sources while SQL is for data storage and recall.  You can store the data in JSON format, like you can store it in any sort of format, but an SQL database is built for it.

Answer (score 2):

JSON is a data interchange format, for effective data storage/management, use the database.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you might be interested in [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/), which stores data directly in JSON and can be accessed via a RESTful API over HTTP.